# Question on fundamental theorem of symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm a little confused on the wording of this statement in my book:

> A is orthogonally diagonalizable and has real eigenvalues if and only if A is symmetric.

They're not saying that only symmetric matrices can have all real eigenvalues, right?

Can matrices that are not symmetric have all real eigenvalues?

Comment: The adverb "*orthogonally*" is the crucial part here.

Comment: consider $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & c\end{pmatrix}$ with $a,b,c\in \Bbb R$. This matrix is not symmetric if $b \neq 0$ but its eigenvalues are $a,c$.

Answer (score 3):

> They're not saying that only symmetric matrices can have all real eigenvalues, right?

No, they say that only a symmetric matrix can: have all real eigenvalues ***and*** be orthogonally diagonalizable.

> Can matrices that are not symmetric have all real eigenvalues?

Sure. You can just pick a triangular (but not diagonal) matrix with real entries on the main diagonal.